# NLog isn't writing an empty custom event propperties into SqlDatabase

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have a few custom event layouts in my configuration like this `{event-properties:item=SomeCustomProperty}`

Filling them out like this:

```
var testLogger = testNLogFactory.GetLogger("Test");
LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, null, "Test");
theEvent.Properties.Add("SomeCustomProperty", null);
testLogger.Debug(theEvent);
```

I have 2 targets, file and database. File target works fine but in case of database this record won't be written as long as SomeCustomProperty value stays null. If I replace `null` with any value, it works just fine.

The corresponding table in the database is correct and allows `NULL` values in `SomeCustomProperty` but if `{event-properties:item=SomeCustomProperty}` has no value the record won't be added to the database.

Is there any reason for this behavior? Is there any workaround?

Comment: `If I replace null with`  With what?

Comment: `{event-properties:item=SomeCustomProperty}` should be `${{event-properties:item=SomeCustomProperty}` of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All layout renderers, like `${event-properties:item=SomeCustomProperty}`, will return an empty string if empty, and not `null`